# How to write a module code for a test bench in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

is it possible to write a module code for a test bench? I have a test bench code that reads a text file and shows it in the Isim but I want to put this data on a port and process it. how can I get it out of simulation environment? how can I write a module for that in VHDL? thank you
, the code is here:

```
 LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use STD.textio.all; --Dont forget to include this library for file operations.

ENTITY read_file IS

END read_file;

ARCHITECTURE beha OF read_file IS 

signal  bin_value : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="000";

BEGIN

  --Read process
     process 
       file file_pointer : text;
       variable line_content : string(1 to 3);
      variable line_num : line;
      variable j : integer := 0;
      variable char : character:='0'; 
    begin
      --Open the file read.txt from the specified location for        reading(READ_MODE).
  file_open(file_pointer,"C:\read.txt",READ_MODE);    
  while not endfile(file_pointer) loop --till the end of file is reached continue.
  readline (file_pointer,line_num);  --Read the whole line from the file
    --Read the contents of the line from  the file into a variable.
  READ (line_num,line_content); 
    --For each character in the line convert it to binary value.
    --And then store it in a signal named 'bin_value'.
    for j in 1 to 3 loop        
        char := line_content(j);
        if(char = '0') then
            bin_value(3-j) <= '0';
        else
            bin_value(3-j) <= '1';
        end if; 
    end loop;   
    wait for 10 ns; --after reading each line wait for 10ns.
  end loop;
  file_close(file_pointer);  --after reading all the lines close the file.  
    wait;
end process;



 end beha;
```

Comment: Just instantiate the entity you want to test, in this testbench module, and use your "bin_value" signal in its port map. Or if I misunderstood and you want to use this entity in aother testbench, just put a port list declaration in the entity specification, and make "bin_value" an output port. What you aclually want to do is very unclear from the question.

Comment: actually i wanted to read a text file so i found a code but it was a testbench code and its ports are isolated, i want to process some data that is in the text file but i cant put the data on any port, it is just show in simulation environment

Comment: @SheydaAlizadeh so you want to synthesize this for an FPGA?

Comment: yes i want to synthesize that